# Superpower parser, parse bracket style accessor

Tags: c#, parsing, superpower

I'm trying to make a parser in Superpower C# parser library to parse a recursive/chained
bracket style accessor. Here is the example of something I want to parse:

`indentifier.identifier[exp][exp].identifier[exp]`

for the dot accessor I'm using the `Parse.Chain` and

```
public enum LangToken
{
    BadToken,
    Identifier,
    ....
    Period,
    ....
}


private static TokenListParser<LangToken, Expression> Identifier { get; } =
            from identifier in Token.EqualTo(LangToken.Identifier)
            select (Expression) new Identifier(identifier);


private static TokenListParser<LangToken, Expression> StaticMemberAccess { get; } =
            from expression in Parse.Chain(Token.EqualTo(LangToken.Period), Identifier, MakeAccess)
            select expression;


private static Expression MakeAccess(LangToken accessor, Expression obj, Expression property)
{
    return new MemberExpression(obj, accessor, property);
}
```

and this works fine, my guess is that I need to change the `Identifier` parser and make it
a i.e. `BracketMemberAccess` (btw I don't have this since I don't know how to implement it.. that's my problem to begin with). But my guess ends there. How can I do this?

Comment: can you post your token and parser definitions along with the definitions for `MakeAccess` and `BracketMemberAccess`?  also you say it "works fine", so what is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: The token and parser definitions are the ones used by the Superpower C# library.. that's what I'm using!

Comment: what version of Superpower are you using?  `LangToken` is not a class or enum in version 2.3.0 which I'm using.  Also, `Identifier` is a static class and not a parser on its own.  Does your code compile?  If so, please add the necessary classes to your question so that it will produce a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That way, I or someone else can help you.